# Disable WebDav Programatically .NET 3.1 or grater

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webdav, windows-server

I am using IIS 8 to host a .NET core 3.1 application.

Recently, I realized that the DELETE http method was not enabled.

After doing some research, I figured that WebDavModule that was blocking it.

I have been trying to programatically disable this feature for some weeks now, and I can manage to do that.

Right now, I am already able to to manually remove WebDav from the Mappings and Modules in IIS. Althoug, every time a redeploy the application, it rises back up again.

Some notes:
I have found the solution for previous versions of .Net core and ASP.NET, by configuring it as disabled in webconfig.json file, but nothing regardind the new versions.

Does anyone knows how to programatically disable WebDav or at least programatically configure it to allwo DELETE requests?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually edit Web.config to disable WebDAV.

In the Web.config file find the  section in the <system.webServer> section. Add `<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>` before . Find the  section in the <system.webServer> section. Add `<remove name="WebDAV"/>` before .

You may need to recycle the app pool or restart IIS for this change to take effect.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response! 

The thing is, .NET core 3+ applications does not come with a web.config file by default. Should I generate one manually?